# When given magnification alone,for an upright, virtual image, with convex lens, how can I find object distance

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, lenses, distance, imaging

Formula involved in such calculations, similar examples, link associated with d question

Comment: Have you done any of your own research? There are many sites on line with equations.

Answer (score 0):

With magnification *alone*? Impossible. You need to know at least something more. Here's, for example, if you also know focal length.

First, one of the standard formulas for magnification is: $m=-\frac{s_i}{s_o}$. Using that and the usual $\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{s_i}+\frac{1}{s_o}$:

$$
\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{s_o}-\frac{1}{m s_o}
$$

$$
s_o = f \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m} \right)
$$

For an upright image, $m$ is positive. For convex lens, $f$ is positive. For an object in front of the lens, $s_o$ is positive and for the image behind the lens, $s_i$ is positive.

For a real image, image and object are on the opposite sides so $s_o$ and $s_i$ are either both positive or both negative. For a virtual image, they are on the same side so they have opposite signs.

Comment: Shouldn't your very first equation have the ratio of image distance to object distance?